# How to find duplicate items based on multiple values using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, list, duplicates

Suppose I have the following class:

```
public class Test{
    public string Length { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

And I would like to find items that have the same value for length and label and counting how many there are for each. So far my code looks like:

```
var dups = testlist.GroupBy(i => new { i.Length, i.Label })
                   .Where(g => g.Count() >= 1)
                   .Select(g => new { Length = g.Key.Length, Label = g.Key.Label, 
                                      Count = g.Count() });
```

But the problem is, the objects in var no longer have the width or height property (they don't exist in g.Key). Is there anyway to find duplicates based on two properties while saving other properties in the result?

Comment: Since each group may have multiple items in it with different widths and heights, which values do you _want_?

Comment: Like in SQL you'd have to choose which ones to take after the grouping. Try g.First() to get the first Width or Height in the grouping.

Comment: (Also the `Where` clause is redundant - if there're no items with a given label and height, there won't be a group for them anyway.)

Comment: So do you want a list/collection of all of the width/heights, do you want the average, first, sum, max, last minimum, or what?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After this

```
testList
  .GroupBy(i => new { i.Length, i.Label })
  .Where(g => g.Count() >= 1)
```

you effectively have an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Test>>`. That's a list of lists of dupes. What more do you want?

Comment: +1 and thanks for reminding me about compiler support for anonymous types.

Comment: Sorry I think I asked the question without thinking it through. Thanks for the answer though.